# Is it possible to have a STATUS column in worksheet 3 from data in worksheet 1 & 2?

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, status, vba

I have a small amount of VB knowledge however I've hit a limitation. I'm trying to figure out how to streamline some code as the existing spreadsheet is getting bogged down once in the 6-8k cells range.

What I need is a way to drop "IN", "Pending", & "Out" in the status column if the value in column A exists in other columns. If Column A value of status exists in Inbound Column A we get "IN", if it exists in Column A of Inbound and Column A of Outbound we get "Pending" and if it exists in both of those columns and column G of outbounds  we get "Out" in column B of Status.

Possible? or Pipe Dream?

Comment: columns, cells, ranges... I am guessing this is not a VB.NET question at all, but excel-vba?  If so, please [edit] your post to correct the tags.

Comment: You should also read [ask] and take the [tour]